# AWK string and value larger than

Tags: linux, awk

I'm digging into some e-mail logs and I want to check what e-mails exceeded a specific size. Practically, in the log, I have the text 'size=' followed by the value. Is there a way to find all values after the word 'size=' that exceed a chosen limit ?

Line examples:

```
Sep  2 02:11:27 mailsys postfix/qmgr[2989]: F24C712000BA: from=<root@mail.ro>, size=462, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Sep  2 03:19:54 mailsys postfix/qmgr[2989]: 863AE1200097: from=<c.ivan@mail.ro>, size=554, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Sep  2 04:01:34 mailsys postfix/qmgr[2989]: A763712000BA: from=<nbounce-24-512645-898600-d25ee-bc28d1c8@nzadev.eu>, size=39992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

I would like to output to a new text file only the lines that exceed 10MB (10485760 bytes).

Comment: Yes it is _absolutely_ possible. Provide few sample lines of the logs containing `size=` and let us know how you want the output to be

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added example lines.

Comment: Appreciate the sample lines, Could you provide them with some lines containing those size of `10MB` along with normal lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming size= is preceded by a space, we could do:

```
awk -v MIN_SIZE=10000 '{ SIZE = 0 } ; / size=[[:digit:]]/ { SIZE = $0 ; sub( /^.* size=/, "", SIZE ) ; sub( /[^[:digit:]].*$/, "", SIZE ) ; SIZE += 0 } ; SIZE > MIN_SIZE { print }' file
```

In details:

```
awk -v MIN_SIZE '
  {
    # Reset size for a new line
    SIZE = 0
  }

  # Process any line including size=
  / size=[[:digit:]]/ {
    SIZE = $0
    # Removing anything before size= 
    sub( /^.* size=/, "", SIZE )
    # Remove anything after the digits
    sub( /[^[:digit:]].*$/, "", SIZE )
    # Convert SIZE to a number
    SIZE += 0
  }

  SIZE > MIN_SIZE {
    print
  }' file
```

Comment: Looks like it worked, I just added the output to another file and I have the desired lines. Thanks for detailing the content. It's the first time I used AWK, I'd better dig into it since it seems capable of many things.

Answer (score 4):

To get all lines with size greater than, as an example, 39900, use:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]+' '$10+0>39900' file
Sep  2 04:01:34 mailsys postfix/qmgr[2989]: A763712000BA: from=<nbounce-24-512645-898600-d25ee-bc28d1c8@nzadev.eu>, size=39992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

How it works:

- `-F'[ =]+'`

  This tells awk to use as a field separator any sequence of spaces or equal signs.  With the field separator defined this way, the size is in the tenth field, `$10`.
- `$10+0>39900`

  This tells awk to print the line if the field 10 (the size) is greater than 39900.  We add zero to field 10 to assure that awk treats field 10 as numeric, not string.

  You can of course, use any number you want for the size limit in place of 39900.  For example, to use 10 MB, 10485760:

  ```
  awk -F'[ =]+' '$10+0>10485760' file
  ```

Comment: I checked the other answer 1st and it worked. Your way (last line) works too but I try not to use the $-field-way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can also try like this using `match()`

Using GNU `awk`

```
awk -v max_size=39990 'match($0,/size=([0-9]+)/,arr) && arr[1]>=max_size' logfile
```

Other `awk`

```
awk -v max_size=39990 'match($0,/size=[0-9]+/){s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",s); }s+0>=max_size' logfile
```

Better Readable

```
awk -v max_size=39990 '
                       match($0,/size=[0-9]+/){
                            s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
                            sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",s); 
                       }s+0>=max_size
                      ' logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/, size=/ {                # if there is size in the record
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # iterate all fields
        if(/^size=/) {            # starts with a size=
            split($i,a,"=")       # split at = 
                if(a[2]+0>39991)  # compare the size value to threshold
                    print         # output if needed
        }
}' file
Sep  2 04:01:34 mailsys postfix/qmgr[2989]: A763712000BA: from=<nbounce-24-512645-898600-d25ee-bc28d1c8@nzadev.eu>, size=39992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```